# I would like to have an id which is dynamic i.e. if I delete id 2 that id 3 becomes Id 2

Tags: php

```
function add($clients){
    $id = end($clients)['id'];
    array_push($clients, ["id" => ++$id,
                            "nom" => $_POST["nom"], 
                            "adresse" => $_POST["adresse"],
                            "tel" => $_POST["tel"]]);
    return $clients;
}
```

Comment: format your code to make it more readable. Otherwise reindexing can be triggered by array_values https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: There's no way to do this automatically in PHP. Why don't you just use the array index instead of an explicit `id` key?

Comment: But why would you want this? If you have the ID in other variables, they'll all need to be updated whenever you delete something.

Comment: we agree the code is correct i would just like to do if i delete a line the other id changes automatically. ex : i have 3 colones 
ID 
1
2
3
if i delete  2 
i want to have
iD
1
2
not
1
3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the array index instead of an `id` key (as suggested in the comments).

However, if for some reason you need a fix along the lines you describe, following (sub-optimal solution) might help:

```
<?php

$clients = [
    ['id' => 0, 'nom' => 'jean', 'adresse' => 'rue duboulanger', 'tel' => '1234',],
    ['id' => 1, 'nom' => 'alice', 'adresse' => 'rue dubouchier', 'tel' => '5678',],
];

$_POST['nom'] = 'alain';
$_POST['adresse'] = 'rue ducoiffeur';
$_POST['tel'] = '9876';

$clients = add($clients); // add a $_POST client

remove($clients, 1); // remove client with id=1 and rebase all id's

function remove(&$clients, $id) {
    foreach($clients as $client) {
        if((int)$client['id'] === $id) {
            unset($clients[$id]);
            $clients = array_values($clients);
            resetIds($clients);
        }
    }
}

function resetIds(&$clients) {
    foreach($clients as $key => &$client) {
        if($client['id'] != $key) $client['id'] = $key;
    }
}

function add($clients){
    $id = end($clients)['id'];
    array_push($clients, ["id" => ++$id,
                          "nom" => $_POST["nom"],
                          "adresse" => $_POST["adresse"],
                          "tel" => $_POST["tel"]]);
    return $clients;
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/odulv)

Comment: do share with us the source of your confusion @devfree

Comment: if i understand correctly i have to use a function i have to change the id so please look at what i just shared at the bottom and tell me what to do thxs

Comment: you see the code sir so now i have to do what the resetIds function like you did or some other idea?

Comment: Now it works with my code but it started with 0;